# Exclude specific slug in 'get_terms'

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, slug, terms

I have a custom taxonomy "role" for my custom post type "People".

When listing the roles, is there a way to exclude roles based on slug and not ID via `get_terms` function?

I ask because I'm running a multisite and a few websites have the same IDs as the ones I'd like to exclude.

Right now I have:

```
<?php
$roles = get_terms(
    'role', array(
    'orderby'       => 'ID',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => true,
    'exclude'       => array('58', '63', '833'),
    ));
$count_roles = count($roles);
if ( $count_roles > 0 ) : ?>
     //do stuff
<?php endif;?>
```

The slugs I'd like to exclude are: `'slug' => ['graduate', 'job-market-candidate', 'graduate-student','research']`, but I don't know where to fit this line, if anywhere.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about including what you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `get_terms()` ([see docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)) function accepts the same args as `WP_Term_Query`([see docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/))
You have to get those terms Ids first and then pass it to the `exclude` arg:

```
// default to not exclude terms
$ids_to_exclude = array();
$get_terms_to_exclude =  get_terms(
    array(
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'slug'    => array( 
            'graduate', 
            'job-market-candidate', 
            'graduate-student',
            'research' ),
        'taxonomy' => 'role',
    )
);
if( !is_wp_error( $get_terms_to_exclude ) && count($get_terms_to_exclude) > 0){
    $ids_to_exclude = $get_terms_to_exclude; 
}
$roles = get_terms(
    array(
        'orderby'    => 'ID',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'exclude'    => $ids_to_exclude,
        'taxonomy'   => 'role',
    )
);

$count_roles = count($roles);

if ( $count_roles > 0 ) : ?>
     //do stuff
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This worked great!  The only edit I had to make was to add `'role', array(` after `$get_terms_to_exclude =  get_terms(`

Comment: Hi @timmyg I've updated my answer to include the ´taxonomy´ parameter, Note that since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array:

Comment: good code, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no option to exclude by slug in `get_terms()`. You'll need to get the IDs of the terms you want based on their slug, *then* exclude those IDs, as in Pabamato's answer.

But you'll probably have better performance just skipping over them on output, rather that slowing down the query with the `exclude`, or making additional queries.

```
$count_roles = count( $roles );

if ( $count_roles > 0 ) :
    $exclude = ['graduate', 'job-market-candidate', 'graduate-student','research'];

    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $role->slug, $exclude ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Do stuff.
    }
endif;
```

Or you could remove the relevant terms from the result set after retrieving them by using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), then proceed as normal.

```
$exclude = ['graduate', 'job-market-candidate', 'graduate-student','research'];

$roles = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'role',
    'orderby'    => 'ID',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );

$roles = array_filter( $roles, function( $role ) {
    return in_array( $role->slug, $exclude ) ? false : true;
} );

$count_roles = count( $roles );
```

Comment: ps: there's actually no need for  the `? false : true` part as `in_array()` is boolean.

Comment: Yes but the value would be opposite to what was needed. The alternative was `! in_array()` but the `!` is harder to see and a *little* less clear about what was happening. I wanted to show the words `true` and `false` to make it more explicit how `array_filter()` worked.